# chaining email forwarders (forward an email to a forwarded address)

Tags: email, mail-forwarding

We can forward a forwarder to an address that is itself forwarded:

first_address@example.com -> second_address@example.com

second_address@example.com -> third_address@example.com

third_address@example.com -> final_destination@example.com

I have tested this, and it certainly works – at least using the cPanel tools. I assume that it may be done infinitely, if one had a need to do so.

However, my question is in regard to **established standards and protocols** (should I ever not have a cPanel just lying around).

Putting aside question of efficiency: **Does a protocol or standard exist for chaining email forwards?** Would I run into a problem on specific server constructs?

Comment: cpanel uses postfix under the hood, it's not a standard it's a config specific to the server, the same can be done on exim, exchange, or others.

Comment: @JacobEvans I've followed your comment with research on `virtual_alias_domains` (etc), and I don't see anything there preventing forwards to another forwarded address. Do you know if there is any particular limitation on this action in postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main risk is loops, that `final_destination@example.com` is not a final destination, but forwards back to either first_address or second_address.

In a loop the message gets forwarded continuously, usually slowly increasing in size because each forward adds one or more headers, until either the maximum message size has been reached, or one of the mailboxes in the mailbox fills up completely and a bounce is triggered.

AFAIK Postfix does loop detection by default, by counting the number of `Received` headers configured with the [`hopcount_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#hopcount_limit) setting. But when a loop also includes a remote domain (that for instance forwards only the message body and not all headers) sometimes loop detection might fail.

Comment: There's also the hilariously entertaining system where the last address in the chain sends a vacation message that bounces right back and causes another vacation message... If you're the sysadmin for the mailserver that falls over, you'll have a great time with that. (Not that I'm bitter...)

Comment: Okay. That `hopcount_limit` is a pretty good insight. You've given me some good ideas about what and how I should monitor this. Thanking all of you!